# Disable autofill popups in Ionic app on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

We have form input fields (`<ion-input>`) in an Ionic v4 (Angular, Cordova) app like these:

`<ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text" inputmode="text" autocapitalize="sentences"></ion-input>`

In the Android app (running on Android 8.1), these autofill "tooltips" show up:

[image]

Is there a way to **disable / get rid of them**? What is strange is that it shows email addresses although the input field is NOT declared as an email field (which could be done by setting `inputmode` to "email" instead of "text").

Versions:

```
@ionic/angular: 4.11.10
cordova-android: 8.1.0
```

Comment: In ion-inpit add attribute autocomplete="off"

Comment: how can we stop the auto complete in ionic v3?, please help us. we are facing some android 8+version OS

Comment: having the same issue , but it suggesting proper values ,,,, but we dont want that suggestion

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text" inputmode="text" autocapitalize="sentences" autocomplete="off"></ion-input>
```

Add autocomplete="off" attribute to your input field. For more reference check ionic documentations regarding inputs. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input

Comment: `autocomplete` value by default is `"off"` (speaking for Ionic 5)